# Create a function that goes over blocks of strings and breaks down each line into subcomponents

Tags: javascript, string, loops, parsing, methods

I have this string block with a unique structure:

```
ABBV08E201902162221     99927781608
ABH5684529845212JB19015037B0984565HCPP
ABTB034T  0084300130310325294     789657
ABTC095C  0084399845285165654     852
ABE05190000000752
```

Each line is broken down further.  For example:

Line 1 "**ABBV08E201902162221     99927781608**" would be:

ID Type 1: A

ID Type 2: BB

ID Type 3: V08

ID Type 4: E

ID Type 5: 20190216

ID Type 6: 2221

ID Type 7: 999277

ID Type 8: 81608

Line 2 "**ABH5684529845212JB19015037B0984565HCPP**" would be:

ID Type 1: A

ID Type 2: BH

ID Type 3: 568452

ID Type 4: 9845212

ID Type 5: JB1

ID Type 6: 9015037

ID Type 7: B09

ID Type 8: 4565

ID Type 9: HCPP

Line 3 "**ABTB034T  0084300130310325294     789657**" would be:

ID Type 1: A

ID Type 2: BH

ID Type 3: TB

ID Type 4: 034T

ID Type 5: 0084

ID Type 6: 3001

ID Type 7: 30310325

ID Type 8: 294

ID Type 9: 789

ID Type 10: 657

Line 4 "**ABTC095C  0084399845285165654     852**" would be:

ID Type 1: A

ID Type 2: BH

ID Type 3: TC0

ID Type 4: 95C

ID Type 5: 008439

ID Type 6: 9845

ID Type 7: 285165

ID Type 8: 654

ID Type 9: 852

Line 5 "**ABE05190000000752**" would be:

ID Type 1: A

ID Type 2: BH

ID Type 3: E

ID Type 4: 051900

ID Type 5: 00000

ID Type 6: 752

Note: There could also be multiple blocks with different values back to back.  NOTE that the block ends withe "**ABE**" string.

```
ABBV08E201902162221     99927781608
ABH5684529845212JB19015037B0984565HCPP
ABTB034T  0084300130310325294     789657
ABTC095C  0084399845285165654     852
ABE05190000000752
ABBV09E333302437771     00027521741
ABH6813597541492QC85469872B6512368HCPP
ABTB852T  7594597557282746984     854
ABTC000C  2172625769517957617     866962
ABTB549T  7865047863545657453     904
ABTC557C  3446574656854656574     763234
ABTB549T  7865047863545657453     V87
ABTC557C  3446574656854656574     985987654475
ABE05190000000752
ABBV09E201902165641     99921484568
ABH5684529845212JB19015037B0984565HCPP
ABTB549T  7865047863545657453     852
ABTC557C  3446574656854656574     852
ABE05190000000752
```

What I'm looking to do is create a function that can:
Loop over each block
Within each block, it breaks it down to each line
Within each line, it breaks it down to their subcomponents

I can't tell if it's better to put the subcomponents into an array, or an object but regardless, I need the subcomponents grouped and to be easily searchable.

I know that there is a for loop to go over each block but I can't figure out how to tell one block from another (much less the other steps).

I know that regex may be involved, and that's fine.  But my regex isn't that strong so I'm still working on it.

Also, I believe that substring() is also a key component.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any logic behind these formats? How do you decide which format is to be used for each line?

Comment: Each line is of a specific format and does have some order.

So referring to the third line: ABTB034T 0084300130310325294 789657:

ID Type 1: A - this will always be a length of 1 and start with "A".

ID Type 2: BH - this will always be a length of 2 and start with "B"; the second letter can differ.

ID Type 3: TB - this will always be a length of 2 and be of random letters.

ID Type 4: 034T - this will always be a length of 4 and be of random letters and numbers.

etc.

Comment: I guess the first major next step is: how do I create a function that can tell one line has ended and the new line has begun?  Is it with regex /n ?

Comment: It's unclear how you distinguish between lines 3 and 4 in your top example (that is, between all the lines that have 3 elements in them). I can get you to an array containing 3 sub-arrays representing the 3 sub-blocks, in which each line of the sub-block is a separate element in the sub-array, if it helps. But I have no idea how to go about splitting each line into ID types.

Comment: That's a good point I failed to mention Jack.

Lines 3 and 4 are actually for the same thing.  To further explain:

Line 1 occurs once and is like an opening statement
Line 2 represents an individual
Line 3 (and line 4 in this case) are similar because it represents the actions of said individual

The final line (ABE) acts as a conclusion and summarizes everything that everyone has done.  So if there were 3 people, it would have "3" and if the total number of actions of everyone is 9, then it would have a "9".

Comment: Looking back, I added far too many ABE lines so I will have that corrected.

Comment: In your new block line 1 (`ABBV08E201902162221     99927781608`) appears twice; is that an error?

Comment: Yes, they should be different.  My apologies on this.  I apologize to everyone: I'm just given a set of rules and I have to recreate an example from it, but the nuances still elude me once in a while.